Not able to detect android sdk in react-native doctor
I have android studio installe, virtual device setup and it can be manually run as well, but not able to detect it when running
react-native doctor 

below is the response:
Android
 ✓ Adb - Required to verify if the android device is attached correctly
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 34.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation

but I have it added to path and all, but still not working:
cs@cs-MacBook-Air ~ % which adb
/Users/cs/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

cs@cs-MacBook-Air ~ % echo $ANDROID_HOME
/Users/cs/Library/Android/sdk

